# Obtain generated debug key/certificate for developing on different machines

Tags: android, build, signature

I'm using Eclipse to develop an app and I have two computers (a desktop and laptop) that I want to use to develop this app. I recently set up my laptop with Eclipse and imported the project over to that computer. However, I realized that I can't launch the application from my laptop onto my phone because the signature that is automatically generated when I build the app from my desktop doesn't match the one that is automatically generated on the laptop; unless I uninstall it on the phone. Does anyone know how to export the automatically generated signature from one Eclipse and import it into another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The automatically generated key is called the debug key/certificate.

You should generate a new key can just copy it over to both your devices. The only negative of this is your builds process is longer as you need a manual steps.

The other option is to copy over the debug key from one of the systems.

You will find the keys in a folder names `.android` in your home directory in Linux & user directory in Windows

Tip: Never loose the certificate once you push an app to the market.

Answer (score 7):

Window -> Preferences |-> Android -> Build:

refer to your custom debug key store, (I copied mine from the C:\Users\${UserName}.android\debug.keystore) which I would put in something like drop box.