# Compile an APK from two different geographic sites

Tags: android, compilation, apk, digital-signature, code-signing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Developing same app on two different computers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776180/developing-same-app-on-two-different-computers)

For professional reasons, I have to compile my code from one PC and sometimes from one other.

The main issue of that manipulation is that my APKs are only of the same signature once every two times.

Is it possible to compile my code so the signature of my APK are exactly the sames from one PC and from one other geographically distant?

I tried to sign my APK as if I put it on Google Play but the problem is that such a process is very long and I compile really often, so this is, to me, not an ergonomic solution.

Comment: Are you using command line compilation by any chance?

Comment: Geography really doesn't matter, the computers can be next to each other, and you'd still have the same problem :)

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776180/developing-same-app-on-two-different-computers?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic steps signing an APK.

1. Generate a private key using keytool
2. Export unsigned APK from Eclipse
3. Sign the APK with the generated private keystore in step 1
4. Verify the APK
5. Align final APK

When you move from one PC to another, just make sure you are using the same exact keystore in step 1 to sign the APK. I think it should not be a problem.

Comment: Then, can I only change on windows my debug.keystore present on C:\Users\UserName\.android\debug.keystore and make them match on both of my computers ?

Comment: leave debug keystore debug keystore -  you will need  valueable keystore for your precious real key ( long, valud for 30 years, protected etc. )  Remember: you can not change signing key once you pushed your app to play store

Comment: @Thordax, this is not a debug.keystore we are talking here. But the generated private key using keytool which also has extension .keystore. Usually you name it accordingly to the app itself. E.g. MyAppNameKey.keystore